# Function works with 'keypress' event, but not with the same 'keypress' event fired by me

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$( '#Example' ).on( "keypress", function( keyEvent ) {

    if ( keyEvent.which != 44 ) {

        myFunction( keyEvent, $(this) );

    } else {

        event.preventDefault();
        var myEvent = jQuery.Event( "keypress" );
        myEvent.which = 46;
        $(this).trigger( myEvent );

    }
});


function myFunction( event, element ) {
    //do stuff
    console.log( "Finished." );
}
```

If a press "." (`which = 46`), `myFunction` do stuffs perfectly, and event "." is inputed. But if a press "," (`which = 44`), `myFunction` do stuffs too, but event "." fired manually is not inputed! In both cases, "Finished" is printed by console.

I need to do on that previous way because if I do as follow:

```
$( '#Example' ).on( "keypress", function( keyEvent ) {

    myFunction( keyEvent, $(this) );

});


function myFunction( event, element ) {

    if (event.which == 44) {

        event.which = 46;

    }

    //do stuff
    event.preventDefault();
    $( '#Example' ).val('.'); //is a example

}
```

as '.' is not being created by the event, but by me manually, an `.on( 'input', anotherFunction() )` event is not being fired.

Finally, `myFunction` is as follow:

```
function myFunction(event, element) {

    var text = element.val();

    if (((event.which != 46 || element.val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) || 
    ((event.which == 46) && (element.val().indexOf('.') == -1) && 
    ((text.length - element[0].selectionStart) > 2))) {

        event.preventDefault();

    }

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
    (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
    (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
    (element[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {

        event.preventDefault();

    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your first function is that you have `event.preventDefault();` which should be `keyEvent.preventDefault();` because event is not defined:

```
$( '#Example' ).on( "keypress", function( keyEvent ) {

    if ( keyEvent.which != 44 ) {

        myFunction( keyEvent, $(this) );

    } else {

        keyEvent.preventDefault();
        var myEvent = jQuery.Event( "keypress" );
        myEvent.which = 46;
        $(this).trigger( myEvent );

    }
});
```

Comment: In fact, should be keyEvent instead of event, but I  made a mistake rewriting the code here trying to  do it more understandable. Should I edit the main post with the correction? Thanks you very much for your response!

Comment: No Worries! Your myFunction is calling on every keypress event and if its 44 then it will call myFunction with 46. What you want to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to trigger the event a second time, instead pass the altered value to the function. Something like this:

```
$( '#Example' ).on( "keypress", function( event ) {
    var key = event.which;
    myFunction( key !== 44 ? 46 : key, $(this), event );
});

function myFunction(key, element, event) {

    var text = element.val();

    if (((key !== 46 || text.indexOf('.') !== -1) &&
      ((key < 48 || key > 57) &&
      (key !== 0 && key !== 8))) || 
      ((key === 46) && (text.indexOf('.') === -1) && 
      ((text.length - element[0].selectionStart) > 2))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
      (key !== 0 && key !== 8) &&
      (element[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```